# Different RGB values for screenshots taken from different screens

Tags: python, selenium, opencv

I'm developing a test automation software where I take screenshot from a webpage with selenium and I process the image with opencv. Now, the software is launched from different screens and when I take the screenshot of a specific image from different screens the RGB values of the image change. Here two examples of the same image taken from different screens:

[image]
[image]
As you can see, RGB values are slightly different. RGB values for me are really important since I process the image using color threshold as for example:

```
from io import BytesIO
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from selenium import webdriver


def get_viewport_size(driver):
    window_size = driver.get_window_size()
    outer_sub_inner = driver.execute_script("""
        return [window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth,
          window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight];
        """)

    return window_size['width'] - outer_sub_inner[0], window_size['height'] - outer_sub_inner[1]


def set_viewport_size(driver, width, height):
    window_size = driver.execute_script("""
        return [window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth + arguments[0],
          window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight + arguments[1]];
        """, width, height)
    driver.set_window_size(*window_size)


SIZE_FOR_GRAPHS = (1440, 798)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1,
         "credentials_enable_service": False,
         "profile.password_manager_enabled": False}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_argument('--force-device-scale-factor=1')
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
set_viewport_size(driver, SIZE_FOR_GRAPHS[0], SIZE_FOR_GRAPHS[1])
scr = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
# Convert img to BytesIO
scr = Image.open(BytesIO(scr))
view_x, view_y = get_viewport_size(driver=driver)
scr = scr.resize((2 * view_x, 2 * view_y), Image.ANTIALIAS)
# Convert to format accepted by OpenCV
scr = np.asarray(scr, dtype=np.float32).astype(np.uint8)
# Convert image from BGR to RGB format
image = cv2.cvtColor(scr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
driver.close()


hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, lowerb=(0, 0, 0), upperb=(180, 255, 255))

imask = mask > 0
masked = np.zeros_like(hsv_image, np.uint8)
masked[imask] = hsv_image[imask]
```

This example is applied to both the screenshots I took with two different screens, my Mac screen and a HP screen connected to my Mac with HDMI. The results of the thresholding on the two screenshots are the following:
[image]
[image]
and obviously the masking is different in the two images.
Is there a way to uniform the RGB values in the process of taking the screenshot from different screens?

**EDIT:**

I set up the monitor colors of the HP monitor equal to the colors of my Mac monitor (LCD colors) and it works fine. I wonder if there is a way to set up the monitor colors with Python or Selenium in order to have fixed colors for the screenshot that the driver take

Comment: Different screens on the same machine or different screens on different machines? If the latter, then there might be differences in how images are saved w.r.t. available libraries for example. Nevertheless, please provide a proper [mre]. As is, it's quite impossible to reproduce your problem using the given code fragment.

Comment: @HansHirse In this example, I used my Mac screen and a HP screen connected to my Mac through HDMI. By the way, I don't know how to provide a proper example since I use my company site for testing and I can't post it here. However I think I can provide it using a random web page so I'll edit the question soon

Comment: @HansHirse I've edited the question adding a full reproducible example

Comment: Likely something to do with colour profiles / colour management.

Comment: It’s not really clear to me what you are asking in practical terms. If you take screenshots, of course that will depend on the screen (plus lots of other things). So taking a screenshot that is independent of the screen seems like a contradiction. Are you looking for *general alternatives* or postprocessing to screenshots perhaps?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi in my test automation software I set up all the parameters (like for example lower bound/upper bound for thresholding, kernel erosion etc.) for when I run the software using my Mac screen; basically I need to find a solution to use the same parameters also for when I run the software on other screens in a way that I don't need to change my parameters everytime I run the software on other screens